# .csproj file formatting options in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm on a small team of developers using visual studio 2010. Some of our workstations save .csproj files with xml elements ending with a space like this:

```
<someelement attribute1="whatevz" />
```

Other workstations save .csproj files with elements ending without space like this:

```
<someelement attribute1="whazzup"/>
```

This causes undue noise in our source control commits. I assume it's caused by a preference one can set in visual studio. Am I right?  How do we adjust this preference?

Comment: No settings for this.  Post this to connect.microsoft.com.  They'll want to know what add-ins are used.

Answer (score 0):

Personally as a dev lead one night, i would make sure all devs have all source checked in and then do a Force Get Latest if you are using TFS...that way you are assured that everyone has the same exact files byte-for-byte.

Comment: we are all working off of the same master svn branch. different users can log into the same machine and use the same code, getting different results for how these project files are saved. To me, this points to either a Visual Studio preferences difference, or a difference in activated add-ins as Hans suggests in his comment on my question.

Comment: Perhaps, I was not suggesting that it was not an issue.  The goal is to reduce the noise, not get a bug reported to MS, which you should do if there is one.  I suggested this path to see if it would work.  It can't hurt to try.